# Could someone tell me why the program does not return any int k in the end?

Tags: c++, algorithm, boolean

I am working on this exercise: A sequence of n integers, each no greater than 1000 (by absolute value), is given. Write program divisors, which finds how many of the given integers have the following property: the integer is divided exactly by m positive divisors (each divisor should not be equal to 1, or to the integer itself).

The result should look like this:
Input:  7 4
        6 20 12 64 1024 50 24
Output: 3
Explanation: The elements of the given sequence with exactly 4 divisors are 20, 12 and 50.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool divisors(int a, int m) {
    int br = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < a; ++i) {
        if (a % i == 0)br++;
        if (br == m) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }


}

int main() {
    int n; // the number of elements
    int m; // the number of divisors
    int a, i, k = 0;

    cin >> n >> m;


    for (i = 1; 1 <= n; i++) {
        cin >> a;
        if (divisors(a, m)) k++;
    }

    cout << k << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't print anything, or it doesn't print what you expect, or you wanted it to actually `return k` when you explicitly wrote `return 0`, or something else?

Comment: it does not print anything actually :/

Comment: basically k should return 4, if you run the example input I wrote in the introduction

Comment: 50 is exactly divisible by 4?Really?

Comment: @SagarPatel no silly! :) 50 has exactly 4 devisors: 2, 25, 10, 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) { // You want to compare with i, not with 1
    cin >> a;
    if (divisors(a, m)) k++;
}
```

Comment: Yes ahhhh I was wondering what was wrong on the bool part THANK YOU VERY MUCH! :D                                THIS IS correct solution now: #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool divisors(int a, int m) {
 int br = 0;
 for (int i = 2; i < a; ++i) 
  if (a % i == 0)br++;
  if (br == m) return 1;
  else return 0;
 
  
 
}

int main() {
 int n; // the number of elements
 int m; // the number of divisors
 int a, i, k = 0;

 cin >> n >> m;
 
 


 for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) { 
  cin >> a;
  if (divisors(a, m)) k++;
 }


 
 cout << k << endl;

 return 0;
}

Answer (score 1):

- Main problem is in your devisor function.Update it like this ,

  ```
  bool divisors(int a, int m) 
  {
     int br = 0;
     for (int i = 2; i < a; ++i)
     {
        if (a % i == 0)br++;
     }
     if (br == m) return 1;
        else return 0;
  }
  ```
- You are returning from function before your for loop completed.

Comment: For some reason maybe for the specific case does not seem to make any difference but will update this part too, thank you! :D

Comment: In your current posted code if you run for loop with paranthesis then it will always give zero result.

Comment: ahh true, apparently I had already modified it changing the parenthesis before running the remark from Viktor to no parenthesis after the                for (int i = 2; i < a; ++i) and then I run it with your suggestion and that's what I said that gave me the same result :)